# OpenEdge ODBC for Access

Tags: ms-access, openedge, progress-db

I cannot update the links in my access to a new ODBC driver.
I believe it to be that OpenEDge 10.1C is not doing a handshake with Access.
The dns will import external data into excel. The error is "error(-7748) the is no message for this error"

Answer (score 1):

Most "weird" errors involving SQL and Progress are a result of the fact that Progress stores *all* data as variable length.  Furthermore most of the data in most Progress databases is created, updated and manipulated by 4GL programs and those programs have no awareness of nor any sensitivity to SQL's ideas regarding column width.

Your first line of defense when you get a strange error trying to query a Progress database with SQL should be to run **dbtool** (on the db server) to fix any possible SQL width issues.  Simply run dbtool (found in the Progress "bin" directory, $DLC/bin/dbtool if the OS is UNIX, use "proenv" to get a command prompt and then %DLC%\bin\dbtool if you are running Windows) and select option 2.  You may want to script this and run it automatically if you frequently have issues.

Comment: I don't quite understand the relevance of variable-length storage here, given that Access's default database engine, Jet/ACE, has always used variable-length storage. That's a db engine detail that your interface layer should completely abstract away from you and shouldn't have any relevance at all with an ODBC driver.

Comment: Even if Access uses variable width fields if it is assuming that it can trust the width information that it gets from the Progress schema then it is going to be disappointed.

I'm just saying that an awful lot of weird issues that people have using ODBC with Progress databases are fixed by running dbtool and fixing the SQL width.  It's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Progress ODBC error -7748 can be solved by adding a registry entry. [This discussion](http://www.progresstalk.com/showthread.php?114231-WorkArounds2-8192) explains the workaround and what it does.

Essentially, the registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\[Your data source name]
```

should be a string value entry named 'Workarounds2', and its value should be set to 8192.

See:
http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/odbc/allodbc/index.html#page/odbc/workaround-options.html